# I want to set custom boundary to multipart/mixed request using Springboot webclient

Tags: spring-boot, multipartform-data, spring-webclient, multipart-mixed-replace

I have this method to prepare multipart request and prepare headers for parts

```java
public MultiValueMap<String, HttpEntity<?>> prepareMultipartRequest(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) throws Exception {
        MultipartBodyBuilder builder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
        
        List<Part> requestParts;
        int i = 0;
        requestParts = new ArrayList<>( httpServletRequest.getParts());
        for ( Part part: requestParts) {
            InputStream inputStream = part.getInputStream();   
            InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(inputStream); 
            
            ContentDisposition contentDisposition = ContentDisposition
                    .attachment()
                    .filename(part.getName())
                    .build();
            
            builder.part(part.getName(), resource)
            .contentType(MediaType.valueOf(part.getContentType()))
            .filename(part.getName())
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, part.getSize()+"")
            .header("Content-ID", (i != 0) ? ("<" + i++ + ">") : String.valueOf(i++))
            .headers(h -> h.setContentDisposition(contentDisposition));
                                      
        }
        
        return builder.build();
    }
```

And this is how i am sending multipart POST request

```
        responseDetails.setResponseBody( 
                    webClientForConnections
                    .method( httpMethod )
                    .uri( outboundconfig.getApiURL(), uri -> uri.queryParams( queryParamMap ).build() )
                    .headers( headers ->  headers.addAll( httpHeaders ) )
                    .body( BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(multipartRequest ) )            
                    .exchangeToMono( response -> processClientResponse( response, responseDetails )  )
                    .timeout( Duration.ofSeconds( outboundconfig.getConnectionTimeoutInSeconds() ) )
                    .onErrorResume( e -> handleExceptionScenarios(e, responseDetails, timeoutValue ) )
                    .block() );
```

I tried setting boundary field on Content-Type header, but it didn't worked